# Load balancing over socket io using haproxy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, haproxy

I have application where clients are two.

1 > Device (socket.io)

2 > Angular (socket.io)

My application is working fine with one server but when I have put in scalable mode then it create problem to make communication between device and angular (socket).

So basically, we need solution where once device connected to a server then some middleware(like haproxy) will help to send all request after that to that particular server only.

Application Uses:

1. Node
2. Socket io
3. Python
4. Angular

Hosted on AWS and uses : EC2,Elastic cache Redis, DynamoDB

Please let me know if you have any query from my question.

Thanks in advance!